# In a project in drf, I have endpoint "api/v1/invoice/#id/" so I want to give access to view to only author of this invoice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have an endpoint /api/v1/invoice/#id/

I want that only author of this invoice should be able to view invoice
Or staff should be able to view this invoice
And superuser should be able to view, update, delete invoice

I tried creating permissions.py file in my app:

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class AuthorGetStaffGetAdminAll(BasePermission):
    edit_methods = ("PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return True
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True

        if obj.author == request.user and request.method not in self.edit_methods:
            return True

        if request.user.is_staff and request.method not in self.edit_methods:
            return True

        return False
```

serializer.py

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id', queryset=order.Order.objects.all())
    id = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = invoice.Invoice
        fields = ['id', 'invoice_series', 'order', 'payment_id']
```

view.py

```
class InvoiceDisplayView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AuthorGetStaffGetAdminAll]

    def get(self, request, invoice_id):
        invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id__iexact=invoice_id)
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoice)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/invoices/<str:invoice_id>/', views.InvoiceDisplayView.as_view(), name="invoice_view"),
]
```

Comment: What issue are you facing here?

Comment: Even if the user who has not created it, he can view the invoice details currently. I want that only owner of that invoice should be able to view it, or staff should be able to view it, and superuser should be able to view, update and delete invoice.

Comment: Did you add this created AuthorGetStaffGetAdminAll in the permission class in your APIView ?

Comment: class InvoiceDisplayView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AuthorGetStaffGetAdminAll]

    def get(self, request, invoice_id):
        invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id__iexact=invoice_id)
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoice)
        return Response(serializer.data)

Comment: @UzzalH.Mohammad Yes I have added see code

Comment: I'm not sure your code looks okay here, can you check the users you are using are normal users and not a stuff or author(creator of that object) or super admin.

Comment: Yes, I have created test cases, in that my user is normal user, not a staff and not admin.

Comment: I tried to change code in has_permission method of permissions.py file in that I tried using this code:
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True

        if request.user.is_staff:
            return True

        return False
but it gives access to staff and admin only how can I check for is owner in this function

Comment: Try one more thing check if this has_object_permission is actually being called and figure out why it is returning true for normal user.

Comment: In which case has_object_permission is called, while we try to get model data like Invoice.objects.get(id=id) at that time it should get called??

Comment: Or can you give me idea how can I check that why control is not coming in this function??

Comment: Do you have serializer class and queryset in the RetriveAPIView ? this permission is checked only for default queryset as far as I know.

Comment: @UzzalH.Mohammad Yes I have serializer but its model serializer and I have updated my question and included all views.py, serializers.py, permission.py files please have a look and suggest me what can I do

Comment: I have added my answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

APIView do not have object level permission check. You can update your APIView with RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView :

```
class InvoiceDisplayView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    
    lookup_field = 'invoice_id'  # primary key
    permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticatedAndOwner]
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
```

if your primary key is invoice_id you can do this and no get method is required, this alone serves put update delete and get all alone,  usually primary_key is just id or pk , in that case lookup_field will be 'id' or 'pk' and you need to update your urls as well :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/invoices/<int:id>/', views.InvoiceDisplayView.as_view(), name="invoice_view"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `APIView` and not generic view, you have to call `check_object_permissions` explicitly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555530/how-to-use-object-level-permissions-with-apiview) explains everything.

Your get method should look like this:

```py
    def get(self, request, invoice_id):
        invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id__iexact=invoice_id)
        self.check_object_permissions(request, invoice)   # This calls permissions
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoice)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```